# C# List<string[]> to List<object[]> Conversion

Tags: c#, type-conversion

All, have I gone mental (this is not the question). I want to convert `List<string[]>` to `List<object[]>`

```
List<string[]> parameters = GetParameters(tmpConn, name);
List<object[]> objParams = parameters.OfType<object[]>();
```

this is not working, but unless I have forgotten something a conversion using this method should be possible (no Lambdas needed)?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You want to use something like:

```
List<object[]> objParams = parameters.OfType<object[]>().ToList();
```

or in C# 4.0, just

```
List<object[]> objParams = parameters.ToList<object[]>();
```

or

```
List<object[]> objParams = parameters.ConvertAll(s => (object[])s);
```

Answer (score 4):

Because of array covariance, in .NET 4.0, you can just do:

```
// Works because:
// a) In .NET, a string[] is an object[]
// b) In .NET 4.0, an IEnumerable<Derived> is an IEnumerable<Base>              
var result = parameters.ToList<object[]>();
```

But note that you wouldn't be able to mutate those arrays with anything other than strings (since array covariance isn't truly safe).

If you want truly flexible writable object arrays, you can do:

```
var result = parameters.Select(array => array.ToArray<object>())
                       .ToList();
```

(or)

```
var result = parameters.ConvertAll(array => array.ToArray<object>());
```

Then you could replace the elements of each inner array with instances of pretty much any type you please.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, dispite my origonal typed question. The first of the above is what I tried but without `var`, why in this case does `var` make the crucial difference - I suppose the answer is that it is doing the cast `ToList()` for me. Awsome really... Thanks for your time.

Comment: `var` isn't required, you could do `List<object[]> result = parameters.ToList<object[]>();`, so I'm not sure where your original attempt went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`OfType<string[]>` returns an `IEnumerable<string[]>`, not a `List<object[]>`.

`Enuemrable.OfType` filters out any invalid casts.  You may want to consider `Enumerable.Cast` instead ,which will throw if you make a mistake.  If `string[]` doesn't inherit from `object[]` (I honestly don't remember), you may need to call `Enumerable.Select` to provide a conversion.

You definately need a Enumerable.ToList call in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it this way

```
List<string[]> sList = new List<string[]> {new []{"A", "B"}};
List<object[]> oList = sList.Cast<object[]>().ToList();
```